# Slow page loading on apache when using Flask

Tags: python, apache, tensorflow, flask, mod-wsgi

### The Issue

I am using my laptop with Apache to act as a server for a local project involving tensorflow and python which uses an API written in Flask to service GET and POST requests coming from an app and maybe another user on the local network.The problem is that the initial page keeps loading when I specifically import tensorflow or the object detection folder within the research folder in the tensorflow github folder, and it never seems to finish doing so, effectively getting it stuck. I suspect the issue has to do with the packages being large in size, but I didn't have any issue with that when running the application on the development server provided with Flask.

Are there any pointers that I should look for when trying to solve this issue? I checked the memory usage, and it doesn't seem to be rising substantially, as well as the CPU usage.

### Debugging process

I am able to print basic hello world to the root page quite quickly, but I isolated the issue to the point when the importing takes place where it gets stuck.
The only thing I can think of is to limit the number of threads that are launched, but when I limited the number of threads per child to 5 and number of connections to 5 in the httpd-mpm.conf file, it didn't help.
The error/access logs don't provide much insight to the matter.

### A few notes:

Thus far, I used Flask's development server with multi-threading enabled to serve those requests, but I found it to be prone to crashing after 5 minutes of continuous run, so I am now trying to use Apache using the wsgi interface in order to use Python scripts.
I should also note that I am not servicing html files, just basic GET and POST requests. I am just viewing them using the browser.
If it helps, I also don't use virtual environments.
I am using Windows 10, Apache 2.4 and mod_wsgi 4.5.24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tensorflow module being a C extension module, may not be implemented so it works properly in Python sub interpreters. To combat this, force your application to run in the main Python interpreter context. Details in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

Comment: Thanks, that really did fix the issue for now.
I am curious, would it potentially cause issues down the line if theoretically multiple people are using the service concurrently? As I understood it from my brief googling, it seems like the idea of having the sub-processes in the first place is to provide environment isolation for each module.

Comment: Sub interpreters are not sub processes. They still run in the same process, so would make no difference. Your code still has to be multithread safe in the context of concurrent requests. That is the case whether or not use sub interpreters. If your code isn't written to be able to handle concurrent requests, then on Windows you will have a problem, as the only concurrency model supported in Apache is threading. You can't specify requests be handled in separate processes.